# ie7 td with input extra vertical space

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

just have found strange problem in ie7 rendering (may be for previous versions else).
If I have input inside td it create cell with height more then other browsers (ff, ie8, chrome).
All margins are reset, paddings removed, cellcpacing to zeroes. The only possibly way to make them equivalent
that I have found is specify height for all tds in pixels. But it seems to me very ugly.

here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="details-table">
        <tr class="details-row">
            <td>
                <label for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="txtFirstName">Last Name</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt-details-row">
            <td>
                <label for="txtFirstName">First Name2</label>
                <input type="text" class="details-input textField" id="txtFirstName2" name="txtFirstName2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="txtLastName2">Last Name2</label>
                <input type="text" class="details-input textField" id="txtLastName2" name="txtLastName2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="details-row">
            <td>
                <label for="txtFirstName3">First Name3</label>
                <input type="text" class="details-input textField" id="txtFirstName3" name="txtFirstName3" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="txtLastName3">Last Name3</label>
                <input type="text" class="details-input textField" id="txtLastName3" name="txtLastName3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

here is css:

```
html,
body,
form,
table,
tr,
td
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}


body
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px ;
}

input.textField
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    height: 17px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px ;
}

.details-table
{
    width:100%;
    color: #666
}

.details-table tr.details-row,
.details-table tr.details-row td
{
    background: #ebe4bc;
}
```

and here is screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

float:left on the elements might help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can fix it by changing the height of either **td** or **input** element, as there's always 1 offset auto generated for that input in IE7 mode. In IE8 or other popular browsers, the extra 1 offset is not generated.

I think it's a bug in IE7.